# Make it so randomized platforms are always reachable by the player

Tags: c#

Everything is fine for the game physics except for that fact that once the player finishes the tutorial level and is put into the next level, the platforms are randomized. This is intended, but I want to make it so that all platforms are reachable no matter where it is. I want it so that when the platform is randomized, all platforms are still reachable to progress through the game.

```
int maxHeight = this.ClientSize.Height - player.Height - ground.Height - 2 * platformHeight;
int minHeight = platformHeight + 50;
int gap = rand.Next(minPlatformGap, maxHeight / 2);
int y = rand.Next(minHeight, maxHeight);

foreach (PictureBox plat in platform)
{
    int x = rand.Next(0, this.ClientSize.Width - plat.Width);

    plat.Location = new Point(x, y);
    y -= gap;

    if (y < minHeight)
    {
        y = maxHeight;
        gap = rand.Next(minPlatformGap, maxHeight / 2);
```

Comment: How far can the player jump? A simple way is to generate platforms that are at most that distance from the player/each other.

Comment: Fascinating problem!  I'm going to bookmark this because I'm really curious about what people will come up with.  Unfortunately, my own expertise with this topic is far too limited to come up with anything useful.  Just wanted to let you know that I like your question.

Comment: This feels like a graph problem. Each platform is a node, and the distance to each other node is an edge. You then need to define your path through the level. So a start and an end node. Then you need to make sure that there is a path from the start node to the end node where all the edges on that path are not too long for the player to jump.